# Output does not match strcmp() function in c

Tags: c++, fgets, cin, strcmp

For comparing two strings by a `strcmp()` function i took one input string by `fgets()` and `cin` and another is given in function as default argument . But when i compare them by `strcmp()` funtion outputs does not match.

```
    char a[20];
    int b;
    cin>>a;
    b=strcmp(a,"ab");
    cout<<b;
```

where i take input `a` as `ab` and `b`'s value is 0 which is completely fine.But when for the same input is taken by `fgets()` then `strcmp()` output is not same as before.

```
char a[20];
    int b;
    fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin);
    b=strcmp(a,"ab");
    cout<<b;
```

where `a`'s value is `ab` and `b`'s value is 1. Why? is that a compiler problem or something else?

Comment: It is not a compiler problem.  The issue is that you didn't read the docs more closely.   [The fgets function docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).  What do you think the second parameter does?

Comment: `fgets` and `cin>>a` do not result in the same string. Please read the documentation for _both_ to get a better understanding of what they do.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie as str will contain that newline character so it gives value 1. is it right?

Comment: @FahimFerojeAlJami - Yes, new lines are not stripped.  Second, you could have discovered this yourself if you wrote a loop and outputted each character in `a` as an integer: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a) ++i) cout << static_cast<int>(a[i]) << "\n";`  Then you would see that there is an invisible control character at the end.  That should have been your first step if there was something you didn't expect, and that is to see what the characters are that make up the `a` string.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets()` does not strip any newline, per section **7.21.7.2 The
`fgets`
function** of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of
>   characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by `stream`
>   into the array pointed to by `s` .  No  additional characters are read
>   after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. 
>   A null character is written immediately after the last character read
>   into the array.